# Selection of IoT develpoment Board

Tags: iot

I am developing a project based on IoT and Cloud Analytics.I want a hardware in which GPS, GSM/GPRS Module and a button can be integrated. On pressing button it will send location to website hosted on Cloud through GSM/GPRS Module. This is what i have in my mind.

I might use Azure and Windows 10 for development. Please help me to buy a cheap hardware which can handle all this efficiently. Just tell me a list of Hardware eligible for my project so that i can purchase according to my budget.

If there is any other OS, IDE ,Cloud or any specific thing which i should target then do tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you to check on [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) and [Arduino Uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). These are two widely used development board, which has a wide range support for sensors/shields, and enables you to develop your prototype product with real ease.

You can either choose Linux or Windows IoT as your embedded OS, depending on your personal taste. Raspberry Pi is officially supported by Windows 10 IoT, and by nature, it should have better support for Microsoft Azure.

You can find a compatible hardware for windows IoT in [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist).

Arduino Uno, on the other hand, should be easy integrated with various development boards/shields, GPS and GPRS modules included.

Also, there's a "Arduino Remote" project available which enables you to connect to arduino devices easily. You can find a tutorial from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/wra).

I hope it helps.